# How to send a file using scp from a perl script using only ftp hostname, login and password, WITHOUT ppk file

Tags: perl, ftp, scp

Hoe to send a file using scp from a perl script using only `ftp hostname,` `login` and `password`, WITHOUT ppk file

This is what I use when I do have ppk file.

```
open scp://username@hostname -privatekey="\path\to\ppkfile\ppkfile.ppk "
put filename.csv /home/destination_flder
exit
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried this module? http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/Net-SCP-Expect-0.16/Expect.pm

Comment: @Suic, on Windows (which seems to be what mongotop uses), Expect only works with Cygwin perl.

Answer (score 4):

one of the possible solution is that u can configure destination machine for passwordless ssh and then 
use the following command to transfer file or copy

```
scp $source_filepath username@machinename:$destination_filepath
```

Comment: great solution!!! except that it's not secure. Thank you very much!!! seems like this is the best suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Suic's recommendation is very good, looks like exactly what you're looking for. Personally I haven't used that particular module, though.

I've had good success with [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.75/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm), which is a perl wrapper for SFTP client. It supports password-based login in most situations (see documentation for details). In my experience SFTP is usually available whenever SCP is and gives greater level of control.

Comment: Net::SFTP::Foreign is **not** a wrapper for the SFTP client, it is a full implementation of the SFTP protocol. It just happen to use the `ssh` binary as its transport layer.